# Magento 2 Products Not Showing in Category page after upgrade to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5p1

Products Not Showing in Category page after upgrade to 2.4.5-p1 and indexer:reindex cmd gives below error

```
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to build 
synonyms"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to build 
synonyms","caused_by":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"parse_exception: Invalid 
synonym rule at line 3","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"term: \" was completely eliminated by analyzer"}}},"status":400}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the issue,the issue was in extra '"' symbol specified in one of search synonyms:

**select * from search_synonyms limit 10;**

[image]

We were able to re-run catalogsearch_fulltext reindex after removing this extra quote.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct version of Elasticsearch installed? Magento `2.4.5-p1` requires version `7.17` of Elasticsearch - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

Comment: Yes We have 7.17 of Elasticsearch.